# Арифметические операции в шаблонах Django

Tags: python, django

Подскажите, существует ли возможность осуществлять арифметические операции с данными непосредственно в шаблонах, и если есть, то как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Шаблоны Django не поддерживают арифметические операции. Единственное, что встроено, - это фильтр add. Если first = 1, а second = 2, будет выведено 3.

```
{{ first|add:second }}
```

Если нужно большее, надо самостоятельно создавать новые фильтры.

Answer (score 3):

[Математические операции в шаблонах Django](http://www.kolger.ru/2009/04/math-in-django-templates).